# how to run a command in many files by running the command only one time?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, perl, join

I would like to run following command on 31 separated file name chr1.txt ... chr31.txt , and get 31 outputs  only by one run.

this is command :

```
 cat input.txt  | sed 's/.\{5\}/& /g' > output.txt
```

any sugesstion please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple loop will do the trick:

```
for((i=1;i<32;i++));do cat chr$i.txt | sed 's/.\{5\}/& /g' > output$i.txt; done
```

Comment: thank you! and if I want to join all these outputs from output1 to output31 sid by side by one run, then what should I do?

Comment: do you mean join them so that one follows another? or each of them in a separate column?

Comment: I mean join them like one follow another. for example outpu1 and output2 join together and then output 3... until output31.

Comment: In that case, just alter the command a bit, like this: `for((i=1;i<32;i++));do cat chr$i.txt | sed 's/.\{5\}/& /g' >> all-in-one.txt; done`

Comment: `for((i=1;i<32;i++));do sed 's/.\{5\}/& /g' chr$i.txt  ; done > output.txt`.  note `cat` isn't necessary here, sed knows how to read files.

Comment: Alternatively: `seq 1 31 | sed -e 's/^/chr/ ; s/$/.txt/' | xargs sed 's/.\{5\}/& /g' > output.txt`

Comment: @cas thank you. and if I want to delete the last coulmn of 31 different file by one run , while column number might be different in different files, and I also do not know each file how many columns have, then what will be the command?

Comment: that should be posted as a different question.  but combine any of the methods above with `awk '{$NF=""; print $0}'` or similar.  e.g. `seq 1 31 | sed -e 's/^/chr/ ; s/$/.txt/' | xargs awk '{$NF=""; print $0}'`

Comment: stdout or wherever you redirect them to.  there's little point in answering any of your questions if you don't even try to understand what the answers mean or how they work.  cargo-culting magic answers you don't understand is no good for anyone, least of all you.

Answer (score 4):

If your shell supports brace expansion you can do:

```
sed 's/.\{5\}/& /g' chr{1..31}.txt >output.txt
```

`chr{1..31}.txt` will be expanded to `chr1.txt`, `chr2.txt` .. `chr31.txt`. The whole output (from all files) will be saved to `output.txt`.

Comment: @zara well you should probably have mentioned that in the question so that any solution can be properly directed :)